# localstorage on button click [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store the currency of my Incremental Game buy clicking on a button.

This is the code:

```
$('#saveGame').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('evoAmountKey','evoAmount');
});
```

and to load the save i used:

```
$('#loadGame').click(function() {
    localStorage.getItem('evoAmountKey','evoAmount');
});
```

but it doesn't work. And how do i save something if the var looks like this?:

```
var hunter = {
    Amount: 0,
    Cost: 75,
    Increment: 5
};
```

can i simply type:

```
$('#load/saveGame').click(function() {
    localStorage.getItem('hunterKey','hunter.Amount','hunter.Cost', 'hunter.Increment');
});
```

Can you give me a example please :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: localStorage.setItem("object",JSON.stringify(object))

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this;

```
var hunter = {
    Amount: 0,
    Cost: 75,
    Increment: 5
};

$("#saveGame").click(
    function() {
       // must stringify the object before save
       localStorage.setItem('hunter', JSON.stringify(hunter));
    }
);

$("#loadGame").click(
    function() {
       var savedHunter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hunter'));
       alert(savedHunter.Cost);
    }
);
```